# Problem in code adds to the same div?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, html

Problem in code adds to the same div? I need it to add multiple divs of the same id.

Atm it takes all the seperate entitys or colums in my database and places them in the one div called  I was hoping it would add for each record in my database which is equal to the userid in my sqlsyntax.

How can I achieve this?

Code:

```
    using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT Wallpostings FROM WallPosting WHERE UserID=" + theUserId + "", cn))

    using (OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        var divHtml = new System.Text.StringBuilder("<div id=mysqlcontent>");
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            divHtml.Append(String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(0)));
        }

        divHtml.Append("</div>");
        test1.InnerHtml = divHtml.ToString();

    }
}
```

}

Example:

```
<div id="test1">
   <div id="mysqlcontent">every record from my database = to the userid is being placed in this single div  </div>
</div>
```

I need it to look like this:

```
<div id="test1">
   <div id="mysqlcontent">record 1</div>
   <div id="mysqlcontent">record 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: wondering !!!!!!!! why would you need all divs with the same id??

Comment: Weird but if you still need it that way then the **<div id=mysqlcontent>** and **</div>** should be in the while loop

Comment: @garrith: no need for single id to apply css, there are a hell lot of ways to achieve this e.g a one line jquery would apply the css to whole lot of divs with different ids.

Comment: could you post an answer to achieving that Vendetta!?

Comment: for Css I would use class="mysqlcontent" and use the id field for a description of what the content of the record actually contains. Then in your style sheet use .mysqlcontent rather than #mysqlcontent

Comment: As an aside, I would be very careful about using string concatenation to build your sql queries in code. This opens you up to a raft of vulnerabilities (perhaps not specifically in this case, but we haven't seen the rest of your code).You need to at least look at using parameterized queries so that you can avoid SQL injection risks. The code near the bottom of this page should be enough to get you started down that road. http://forums.asp.net/p/1090296/1634550.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT Wallpostings FROM WallPosting WHERE UserID=" + theUserId + "", cn))

    using (OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        var divHtml = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            divHtml.Append("<div id=mysqlcontent>");
            divHtml.Append(String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(0)));
            divHtml.Append("</div>");
        }


        test1.InnerHtml = divHtml.ToString();

    }
}
```

Furqan is right, though. It's a bit odd to have multiple elements with the same id.

Comment: this is the answer! Thank you I do however have another problem its taking the content out of my database backwards i.e oldest first? How do I set it to take out newest first?

Comment: Hi Garrith. It sounds like you want an 'ORDER BY' clause in your SQL query. It's hard to give you the exact query because I don't know the column names. Here is a good explanation of ORDER BY: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

Comment: Thanks man that answered all of that now I need to add a new question that hopefully you might be able to answer again? Should only take you a second as you already understand what ive done here.

Comment: Sure. What is your new question?

Comment: Sorry went to write it when I posted that should have posted then wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT Wallpostings FROM WallPosting WHERE UserID=" + theUserId + "", cn))
using (OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{       
    var divHtml = new System.Text.StringBuilder(); 
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var divHtml.AppendFormat("<div class=\"mysqlcontent\">{0}</div>", reader.GetString(0));
    }

    test1.InnerHtml = divHtml.ToString();

}
```

This way you generate a new `<div>` on every iteration in your while loop. Also note that I'm using "mysqlcontent" as the *class* of the `<div>` instead of the *id*. Each id should only be used once in your entire HTML-page.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is one way to rectify your code

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    var divHtml = new System.Text.StringBuilder("<div id=mysqlcontent>");
    divHtml.Append(String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(0)));
    divHtml.Append("</div>");
    test1.InnerHtml += divHtml.ToString();
}
```